# Is django-admin part of python or django installation?

Tags: python, django

I am just starting out on using the django framework. One thing that bugs me is the django-admin utility. Is it part of the python installation or is it part of the django installation through pip?

The way I've been doing my projects is

1. Make a virtual Environment.
2. Create a django project in the environment through django-admin.
3. and then I just install the django framework using pip inside the environment.

My question arises because inside the virtual environment, I used django-admin to create the project before installing the framework.

Comment: How did you create your environment? no part of the Django framework is native to Python, there were probably some pre installed packages in your environment, you can check by running `pip freeze` after creating the environment.

Comment: I don't understand step 3 -- you would not have been able to perform step 2 unless django was already installed.

Comment: I create the virtual environment using mkvirtualenv myenv  command. I have installed the django framework outside of the environment(globally), but everytime I create a new environment to work in, I have to re-install the framework before I can run the server. However, django-admin works fine even before installing the framework in the virtual environment, hence the confusion.

Comment: I have the same problem. The solution would be install django globally to start a django project in which you create the env and install django again in the env. Maybe if there was a way just to have the django-admin as a standalone?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/

> django-admin is Django’s command-line utility for administrative
>   tasks.

`django-admin` utility comes with any Django installation. inorder to use django-admin command, the `django-admin` script should be on your system path if you installed Django via its setup.py utility. If it’s not on your path, you can find it in `site-packages/django/bin` within your Python installation.

use the link given above to find the instructions for windows as well as linux.

and to answer your question, **django-admin is a part of django framework**

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into something similar. Where in a virtual enviroment I create for python 3 used my global python 2 installation. Try creating a new virtual environment just like before, and this time try using "python django-admin" instead of just "django-admin". A question for you, is this a Windows environment, I ask because that is the only environment I have witnessed this behavior in. I believe by using "python django-admin" it will force it to use the virtualenv's sandboxed python.

Comment: Yes this is in a windows Environment.

Comment: Im sorry, I just noticed that I did not answer you question. No, django-admin is NOT part of python, just a part of Windows.

Comment: It cant be part of windows.

Comment: you cant start a django project without installing python and the django framework, hence django-admin is not a valid command outside of django/python.